# Software for scanning/printing documents in a large size for visually impared student

Tags: printing, accessibility

I work in a school where a lot of standard physical (non electronic) documents need to be re-worked and re-printed in a larger font size so that a visually impared student can read them.

This is straightforward for pure text documents, as the teaching assistants can just re-type them into Word and print at a larger font size.

However there are a number of documents that contain illustrations, graphs and text in a non-linear format that would be impossible to reproduce in this way.

The time-consuming solution is to scan or photograph these documents, and then break them up into sections using standard image editing software or MS office software, and then increase the size of those sections to fill a whole page, and then print each highly zoomed section, so the student can read it.

Is there any software that can achieve this in a simple and easy to use manner? i.e. take an image of a document, and then allow the user to quickly break it up in to sections and then print those section blown-up so they fill the whole page?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I assume the software should run on Windows? How much would you be willing to pay if it comes to commercial solutions? What languages must be supported? Must the text be text (i.e. the software needs an OCR component), or would "plain image files" (optionally joined to PDF files or the like) be sufficient?

Comment: Did you try basic zoom functions built into mspaint or paintbrush?  Open a scan in mspaint or paintbrush depending version of windows.  File print, and scale to 800% then it says you need 8x10 pages, and you print that, and tape them together.  Obviously, 800% might be a bit extreme, you could use a lower number for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes Windows, cheap as possible really, no OCR required, plain image fine. Actually MS paint might be a really good simple idea! The image could easily be cropped and zoomed to fill an A4 page. Thanks.